# Else if statement with Selenium doesen't work

Tags: c#, selenium, if-statement

I have to test a website with Selenium in C#. On the Site, there are buttons(10) in random order. The program should check if the Button is available or not.

Below, I created an else-if statement, but it doesn't work. The program doesn't click anything.

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK")).Displayed)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnK")).Click();
}
else if (driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Displayed)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Click();
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you step through in a debugger? The easy answer is "Neither button is displayed".

Comment: Have you confirmed that calling `Displayed` on these elements will return `true` when it is the correct button? Providing some sample html might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @mrfreester Hey I saw this part of code on following web page(http://cheryjose.blogspot.cz/2013/03/learn-selenium-2-my-first-selenium.html). So I've tried the code on the facebook login page. (E.g it should click the login button)

Answer (score 0):

This is only if and else  if it is possibility to not true both statement if it is if and then else then one of them will run .. but here there is chance to run none of them

Comment: your conditions are getting false both